# Check form action and hide a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hide, action

I need the jQuery code for the following: If the form action is a specific link, then I need to hide certain elements inside it.

```
<form action="/sites/page1.aspx">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
</form>
```

If the form action is `/sites/page1.aspx` then I need to hide class A

```
<form action="/sites/page2.aspx">
    <div class="A"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
</form>
```

If the form action is `/sites/page2.aspx` then I need to hide class B

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr & http://api.jquery.com/hide

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($('form').attr('action') == '/sites/page1.aspx') {
    $('form .A').hide();
} else if ($('form').attr('action') == '/sites/page2.aspx') {
    $('form .B').hide();
} else {
    // do whatever you want
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('HELLO -> ' + $('form').attr('action'));
  if ($('form').attr('action') == '/sites/page1.aspx') {
      $('form .A').hide();
  } else if ($('form').attr('action') == '/sites/page2.aspx') {
      $('form .B').hide();
  } else {
      // do whatever you want
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>

  <form action="/sites/page1.aspx">
      <div class="A">Hello</div>
      <div class="B">It's me</div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as simple as a CSS rule, no need to do any jQuery, which is a good thing since it will work even if Javascript is switched off in the browser:

```
form[action=\/sites\/page1.aspx] > .A, form[action=\/sites\/page2.aspx] > .B {
    display: none;
}
```

And you can generate this into a `style` tag if you need it dynamically, or write it into an external CSS if you have a predefined set.

Answer (score 0):

Give some id to your form tag like id="myform" and in javascript try document.getElementById("myForm").action and you will get the action URL. Rest you can do with little efforts by adding condition in your javascript :-)

Example with JQuery ypu can use on load :

```
$( window ).load(function() {
var form = $('#myform').attr('action');
if(form == '/sites/page1.aspx'){
//Code to hide your DIV ;-)
}
}
```

Comment: It's not working. sorry. It's actually a sharepoint site, which I can't edit a form. So trying to control using jquery